# Docker compose cannot pull images failing with Network Unreachable

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have a script to pull some images from docker registry but it's failing
I have an Ubuntu 20 and docker installed with version 24.0.2 and docker-compose version is 1.25.0. I am getting this error.

[image]

Can someone help me understand what is wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It should an issue if your DNS.

Print the content of the file and read the nameserver IP.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then try to reach that IP with:

```
ping <nameserver-ip>
```

If you're not able to ping it, add end of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file another nameserver:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```